# Laravel controllers filter issue

Tags: php, laravel

I have this filter method defined in filters.php

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
        }
    }
});
```

when i add this code to controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('auth');
}
```

it gives me the famous route exception of laravel at `Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php`

Comment: did you try `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: stil having the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to put that in controller. You can attaching a filter to a route or controller in route.php. Let say you have multiple route that u want to check if the user guest or not. So, in routes.php you can define group filters. If you define that in controller you must attach the filter to every controller. See example below:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
  Route::get('user/account', 'UserController@account');
  Route::get('user/settings', 'UserController@settings');
  Route::get('post/create', 'PostController@create');
  Route::post('post/store', 'PostController@store');
  // ...
});
```

**Example**

Auth Filter

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
  if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

Attaching Auth Filter to controller

```
Route::get('user', array('before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'));
```

Comment: One question, those routes which are defined inside the Route::group, show they be defined outside the group too ?

Comment: You means those route inside route::group must be define outside the group too? If that your question, the answer is no.